# Filter Values Module of 3

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm getting an error when filtering an array

> The operator % is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int

How do I get the iteration value using Java 8?

```
int[] values = new int[9000000];
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    values[i] = random.nextInt(9000000) + 1;
}

long counter = Stream.of(values)
    .filter(x - > x % 3 == 0) // Error here
    .count();
System.out.println(counter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays.stream` or `IntStream.of` instead. `Stream.of` is a generic method, which interprets the array as one element (Java generics do not support primitives).

```
long counter = IntStream.of(values)
  .filter(x -> x % 3 == 0)
        .count();
```